# When using template and inheritance together, I do not know how to override a member function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following code that mixes template and inheritance.

Class `Base` has some utility function to build items (the `work` in the sample code), and `Child` call the `work` in its implementation of the API `call`.

In this function

```
virtual void call() override {
        Base<T>::work(); // Problem Here
        // work();
}
```

I try to call `work()` but got the following error:

```
test.cc: In member function ‘virtual void Child<T>::call()’:
test.cc:18:2: error: there are no arguments to ‘work’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘work’ must be available [-fpermissive]
```

So I write `Base<T>::work()` and makes it work.

Now I have a `Grandson` class, who want to override the `work` function. But the override does not work as in `Child<T>::call` I have explicitly specified calling `Base<T>::work()`. So what's the correct way to implement `Child<T>::call` to make the override in `Grandson` work?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Base {
protected:
    virtual void work() {
        T a;
        std::cout << "From Base" << '\n';
    }
public:
    virtual void call() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Child : public Base<T> {
public:
    virtual void call() override {
        Base<T>::work(); // Problem Here
        // work();
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Grandson : public Child<T> {
        protected:
                void work() override {
                        std::cout << "From Grandson" << '\n';
                }
};

int main() {
        Grandson<int> g;
        g.call();
}
```

Comment: What if you write `this->work();` instead of the `Base<T>::work()`?

Comment: Cannot believe I did not even try this. I must have assumed `work()` is always equivalent to `this->work()`. If you can post an answer I will accept it. BTW, I am not clear about what the error mean. If you can help me it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you also tried Base::work()? I think its just because you are not supposed to template that call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Base<T>::work()` with `this->work()`.

---

When you are a template class inheriting from a base class dependent on your template parameter, the compiler doesn't look into your base when it sees something like `work()`. Instead, you have to tell it that it needs to do that. The easiest way I know of to accomplish that is to prefix the call with `this->`.

As for why it does not work when you use `Base<T>::work()`, I am not entirely sure. It's hardcoding it to call the base class implementation, but I'm fairly sure there's a similar syntax that does work.